# How to understand a recreated hosted zone is ready for DNS validation of an ACM certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I have deleted and created an AWS Route 53 hosted zone and I want to add an public SSL certificate created and managed by Certificate Manager (ACM) Service.

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DeleteHostedZone.html#delete-public-hosted-zone-stop-routing) state that creation may take up to 48 hours to complete:

> If you delete a hosted zone, you can't undelete it. You must create a new hosted zone and update the name servers for your domain registration, which can require up to **48 hours** to take effect.

The question is: **How would I know if the recreated hosted zone is ready** to have a CNAME record set attached to validate the ACM certificate? Should I sit back for 48 hours to guarantee it?

**Note:** I am creating the certificate with Cloudformation and if the certificate is not validated in 12 hours, the stack creation fails and rolls back. That's why I cannot put the CNAME record on the hosted zone instantly and wait for it to be validated whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mostly has to do with whether the domain can actually resolve. So presuming that you have some sort of record configured, you can verify that it resolves.

A simple test would be to create a TXT record, or some other record in the domain, and then resolving that using `dig`, `drill` or `nslookup`.

Example: `dig example.com` will return results such as:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48750
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        4257    IN  A   93.184.216.34

;; Query time: 9 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sat May 18 21:29:18 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

The line to look for here is `example.com.      4257    IN  A   93.184.216.34`, which means it resolved successfully.

Comment: A Route53 hosted zone, indeed, is generated with default record sets (one NS and one SOA), so I do not need to bother with creating a test record set. If it is ok and you mean the important section is `;; ANSWER SECTION:`, mine does not have one yet :)

Comment: @vahdet yeah, that should work, or you can simply look for the SOA or NS record.

Comment: Upvoted as it is great info supplied. However, I have observed that the certificate was issued even if no `ANSWER SECTION` appeared. It's interesting.

Comment: @vahdet yeah, that's to be expected. TTL depends on when the server asked last, so your local resolver might be different than AWS's resolver. You can do `dig +trace  example.com` to get around that